# C# Automapper and List of parent type not mapping childs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I've tried mapping the children of FirewallRule and when the controller receives the payload, firewallDto is not mapped with the DestinationPorts.
The data is trimmed and the structure is stopping at FirewallRule.

I've tried multiple mapping profiles for AutoMapper and it didn't work, searched everything, but didn't get the expected result.
If I read the body, and drop firewallDto, then the payload looks as expected, so I assume that either the mappings I've tried weren't good enough or I'm missing something which I don't see.

So to summarize, if DestinationPorts is in payload, map to NetworkRule and if FqdnTags is in tags, map to ApplicationRule.

If I missed something in the post, I'll edit it.

Payload:

```json
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "priority": 0,
  "action": "string",
  "rules": [
        {
            "ruleType": "NetworkRule",
            "name": "myName",
            "description": "mydescription",
            "DestinationPorts": [""]
        }
  ]
}
```

How it looks in the controller:

```json
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "priority": 0,
  "action": "string",
  "rules": [
        {
            "ruleType": "NetworkRule",
            "name": "myName",
            "description": "mydescription"
        }
  ]
}
```

Code:

```cs
// Classes
public class Firewall 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public List<FirewallRule> Rules { get; set; }
}

public class FirewallRule
{
    public string RuleType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRule : FirewallRule
{
    public string[] FqdnTags { get; set; }
}

public class NetworkRule : FirewallRule
{
    public string[] DestinationPorts { get; set; }
}

public class FirewallDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public List<FirewallRuleDto> Rules { get; set; }
}

public class FirewallRuleDto
{
    public string RuleType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class NetworkRuleDto : FirewallRuleDto
{
    public string[] DestinationPorts { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRuleDto : FirewallRuleDto
{
    public string[] FqdnTags { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
// Mapping
CreateMap<Firewall, FirewallDto>().
    ReverseMap();

CreateMap<FirewallRule, FirewallRuleDto>()
    .Include<NetworkRule, NetworkRuleDto>()
    .Include<ApplicationRule, ApplicationRuleDto>().
    ForMember(dest => dest.RuleType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RuleType));

CreateMap<NetworkRule, NetworkRuleDto>()
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<ApplicationRule, ApplicationRuleDto>()
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<FirewallRuleDto, FirewallRule>()
    .Include<NetworkRuleDto, NetworkRule>()
    .Include<ApplicationRuleDto, ApplicationRule>();

CreateMap<FirewallDto, Firewall>().
    ForMember(d => d.Rules, op => op.MapFrom(s => s.Rules));
```

```cs
// Controller
public async Task<ActionResult<Firewall>> NewFirewall(FirewallDto firewallDto) 
{
    // code
}
```

Tried multiple mapping profiles for automapper, simple classes, scraped google for automapper configurations, search stackoverflow too, and searched for ideas also from chat-gipity without success.

Comment: Is the DestinationPorts in payload empty?

Comment: It is. I've found that I can use Type Descriptors in the class, but it's not entirely what I wanted...

Answer (score 0):

I think the models are over complicated. In your controller `NewFirewall(FirewallDto firewallDto)`, the FirewallDto won't receive enough payloads because it doesn't have property of either "DestinationPorts" or "FqdnTags". You could make them nullable property in order to make these property receivalbe. Then map them conditionally to the right model. You could try following:
FirewallRuleBase.cs

```
    public class FirewallRuleBase
    {
        public string RuleType { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

FirewallRule.cs

```
    public class FirewallRule : FirewallRuleBase
    {
        public string[]? DestinationPorts { get; set; }
        public string[]? FqdnTags { get; set; }
    }
```

ApplicationRule.cs

```
    public class ApplicationRule : FirewallRuleBase
    {
        public string[] DestinationPorts { get; set; }
    }
```

NetworkRule.cs

```
    public class NetworkRule : FirewallRuleBase
    {
        public string[] FqdnTags { get; set; }
    }
```

condition map

```
if (firewallRule.GetType().GetProperty("DestinationPorts"))
{
    result = _mapper.map<ApplicationRule>(userInfo);
}
if (firewallRule.GetType().GetProperty("FqdnTags"))
{
    result = _mapper.map<NetworkRule>(userInfo);
}
```